# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() in JobService

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, background, jobservice

I am adding a JobService to my app using which I need to access an API every 2 hours.

I have added the JobService code below and scheduled it in my SplashActivity where I have my API function to get data from server but it is throwing this error.

Please help. I am not able to understand how can I use this API using JobService.

MyJobService:

```
      public class MyJobService extends JobService {
private static final String TAG = MyJobService.class.getSimpleName();
boolean isWorking = false;
public boolean jobCancelled = false;

// Called by the Android system when it's time to run the job
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job started!");
    isWorking = true;
    // We need 'jobParameters' so we can call 'jobFinished'
    startWorkOnNewThread(jobParameters); // Services do NOT run on a separate thread

    return isWorking;
}

private void startWorkOnNewThread(final JobParameters jobParameters) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doWork(jobParameters);
        }
    }).start();
}

private void doWork(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    // 10 seconds of 'working' (1000*10ms)

    new SplashActivity().productsDetailsApi();


    Log.d(TAG, "Job finished!");
    isWorking = false;
    boolean needsReschedule = false;
    jobFinished(jobParameters, needsReschedule);
}

// Called if the job was cancelled before being finished
@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before being completed.");
    jobCancelled = true;
    boolean needsReschedule = isWorking;
    jobFinished(jobParameters, needsReschedule);
    return needsReschedule;
}


}
```

SplashActivity:

```
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPeriodic(120000)
            .build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Job scheduled!");
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Job not scheduled");
    }
```

Comment: why do you need to call SplashActivity from within service? can't you do the work inside the service? think that is where the issue comes in at.

Comment: @AndreiChernyshev I used productDeatilsApi() function directily in service class but it is not working at all